# Images can't be displayed on iOS simulator or iDevice

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am using correct type "png" and every thing was ok, all images was displayed, but now I can't see it.

in the Targets>> MyProject>>Build phases>>Copy Bundle Resources>> I have all images folders
Also, I have these folders in MyProject Test but did not appear on iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all images that in MyProject>>MyProject folder. 
Then added it again and choose "copy items into destination" which I didn't choose it before. 
Finally, I rearrange my images into groups.
And It works on simulator and iPad

Answer (score 0):

**Simulator is not case sensitive, however iPhone / iPad is case sensitive.**

**I'm sure this is your problem.**

e.g.

Your code have:

```
[UIImage imageNamed: @"Image.PNG"]
```

but the image in the bundle is something like:

```
image.png
```

**EDIT:**

It is the same in the Storyboard, image file name and image name in the storyboard should be the same.

[image]
[image]

Comment: No..I did not use any image in the code, I only used it in the storyboard. and every thing was ok before connect iPad with Xcode.                        Note: the same project is running well on another MacBook. I also tried to delete Xcode and reinstall it but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Again, your problem is in the name of the image. I'm sure that the name of the image file do not match with the name of the image in Xcode. Doesn't matter if it is in the code or in the Storyboard.

Comment: Both of them have the same name and style

Comment: My code hasn't any part related to the images, and I can't share photo here. There is any thing I must check it?